# are contains function in mariadb vs. contains methods in python shapely the same?

Tags: python, mariadb, shapely

I am replicating logic used in our service which uses MariaDB 10.2.21. For given polygon I need to check whether a point is contained inside polygon or not.

In MariaDB we use `Contains(polygon, point)` in python I am replicating such behavior by using `polygon.contains(point)`

from both documentations https://mariadb.com/kb/en/contains/, https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html

but I am unsure what version of mariaDB documentation is referring to, where can I find documentation for mariaDB 10.2.21? Or can someone explain how each methods operate? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the MariaDB documentation says: the MariaDB and MySQL CONTAINS() function only operates on the bounding rectangle of a polygon. So CONTAINS(polygon, point) will even return TRUE when the point its actually outside the polygon, but in its bounding rectangle.

What you are looking for is the ST_CONTAINS() function, this will indeed check against the actual polygon: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st-contains/

ST_CONTAINS() and the shapely contains() method should behave the same

Comment: what would be mariadb contains() equivalent in shapely? Also I am also reading the mariadb doc but not understanding `object bounding rectangles` what does it mean...?

Comment: @Ambleu - Think of a square (the "bounding rectangle") circumscribed around a circle (the "object").  The square is easy to work with -- two x's and two y's.  The circle (or something more complex) inside requires much more work to determine "contains".

Comment: "what would be mariadb contains() equivalent in shapely?" ... I don't think there is any direct equivalent in shapely. 

"bounding rectangles what does it mean" it is a rectangle that contains all of the polygon, sort of the smallest box you'd need to fully put the polygon in. Unless the polygon is an upright rectangle itself, the bounding rectangle will be larger than the actual polygon. Maybe this example from one of my GIS talks helps?

https://image.slidesharecdn.com/fosdem-2014-mariadb-gis-140203045309-phpapp01/95/osm-data-in-mariadb-mysql-all-the-world-in-a-few-large-tables-5-638.jpg

Comment: the background behind the bounding rectangle stuff was that early MySQL GIS would store xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax in spatial indexes only, and for "contains" for a point would simply check xmin<=x<=xmax and ymin<=y<=ymax, but would not take the true geometry into account. Code that actually checks the polygon bounds was only added later, it still uses the MBR approach to identify candidates first, but then goes the extra step of checking against the true geometry. So that's the diff. between CONTAINS() and actual true ST_CONTAINS(), which was only added later, first by MariaDB, then by MySQL